# Python - create multidimensional array index without using numpy

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a list of integers, the length of the list is not fixed, maybe 2, 3, 4 etc., I want to take the length of the list as the number of dimensions of a multidimensional array, each integer in the list is the number of elements of each dimension. e.g. alist = [2,3,4], the generated indexes are:

```
[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,0,3],
[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[0,1,2],[0,1,3],
[0,2,0],[0,2,1],[0,2,2],[0,2,3],
[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,0,2],[1,0,3],
[1,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],
[1,2,0],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[1,2,3]
```

alist = [2,3], the generated indexes are:

```
[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],
[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]
```

I couldn't figure out how to do in Python, and I don't want to use numpy.

Thanks for all reply, i got:

```
alist = [2,3,4]
li = []
for i in alist:
  b = list(range(i))
  li.append(b)


p = product(*li)
l = [x for x in p]
print(l)
```

Comment: Why not numpy? It's orders of magnitude faster than raw python

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```py
import itertools

p = itertools.product(range(2),range(3),range(4))
l = [x for x in p]
print(l)
```

For the alist with unknown length, store the argument in a list, then use `*args` to expand them.

```py
alist = [5,6,7,8]
args = [range(x) for x in alist] # create the arg list
p = itertools.product(*args) # expand args
...
```

Comment: the dimension is not fixed, it's the length of alist, alist might be [2,3,4], might be [5,6], [7,8,9,10]. How does product take alist  as the argument?

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product` of the `range`s for each dimension https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product
alist = [2,3]
iterables, repeat = alist
data = list(product(range(iterables),range(repeat)))
>>>[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: Could you include a short explanation of why you chose this approach? Perhaps compare it to numpy functionality?